# How do I format the x-axis on Python Ggplot?

Tags: python-ggplot

I need to format dates on a x-axis ggplot for python bar chart.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use scale_x_date() to format dates on the x-axis.

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='date'), data) + geom_bar() + scale_x_date(labels='%m-%Y')
```

This gives number of month and the year, for example, 01-1990
You can try other formats.

Comment: Does anyone know a good resource URL to look up the different formats available?  I am trying to work with dates that represent daily data and I think I want x to plot the points for each day.  This URL has a few examples but not what I am looking for:  http://blog.yhat.com/posts/ggplot-for-python.html